# How to model a Machine learning problem considering links between features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-engineering, machine-learning-model

Context:

To predict employee turnover ( will an employee leave? ), I have used one of the classification algorithms (LDA) to train my dataset, and then make predictions.

The dataset is quite small (500 lines), some 20 features, the following are some examples:

- Age
- Years_Spent: Years for an employee has spent in the company.
- Department (IT, Commercial, Management...)
- Salary
- Salary_Increase
- Sale_Bonus
  ...

However, HR Experience tells us that:

1. **For employees whose Years_Spent < 1.5, Salary_Increase is a feature that does not have any impact on turnover** (Because of `Salary_Increase > 0 only when Years_Spent >1.5`).
2. **Sale_Bonus will not have any impact on those who are not commercials**. (Because IT guys will never recept sale bonus)

Here comes the problem:
If I set *`Salary_Increase = 0 for employees whose Years_Spent <1.5`* and *`Sale_Bonus = 0 for those who are not commercials`*, the classification algorithm will take 0 as a very small value, so a possible conclusion could be drawn by an algorithm: "employeeA will leave because he never receives sale_bonus",  (However, in reality, employeeA is from IT department, employeeA receive never sale_bonus and employeeA will not leave because of that), as we see, the constructed model is not correct.

My question is: How to handle this kind of problem so that HR experience can be understood by classification algorithms?

Thank you for your patient reading and kindly welcome all sorts of discussions!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

What you are describing above is known as an **interaction**.

You should consider the algorithm you wish to use and whether it allows for interactions between predictors. Some techniques - like generalised linear models - will require interactions to be stated explicitly, while tree-based algorithms will capture interactions automatically.

Comment: Just an addition about bradS answer. Indeed linear models require explicit interactions to be stated. What it means is that you have to create features that modelize the interactions such as cross-features for instance. You can also use polynomial kernels for instance.

Comment: Thank you bradS and Alexis.  Here is a recap of what I consider to do for next step: 1. Manually create new numeric features x1*x2; x1/x2...; or create category features like "Years_Spent <1.5", "Years_Spent >1.5 and  0% < Salary_Increase< 1%";  "Years_Spent >1.5 and  1% < Salary_Increase< 2%" ... 2. Test / Validation of generalized linear models.   To go further, I may test tree-based algorithms or neural networks to automatically find feature interactions relationship.  Let me know if you have further remarks! Thanks a lot!